# Can I upload a video game screencast to Vimeo?

Tags: copyright, vimeo

I wonder whether video game screencasts are within Vimeo's Terms of Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the relevant line from the Vimeo Guidelines (https://vimeo.com/help/guidelines):

> No screen-captures of video games or gameplay videos, even if edited. (Exception! Game developers can upload examples of their own work. Machinima videos with a story also are allowed, but must be labeled as such in the video description to avoid deletion.)

So, basically, it's not allowed unless you created the game or you're using the screencasts to create a narrative.